# Can Windows manage multiple focus points on a single control?

Tags: delphi, focus, custom-controls, delphi-7

I'm building a custom control which is to have multiple focus points. For example, within 1 control, let's say there's 3 regions (could be defined as a rect on the canvas) which are to be able to have focus. Depending on which one has focus, I don't want the default Windows dotted line around it, but some special handling. I know nothing about how to even give 1 custom control its own focus.

The original project was a single TPanel with a few VCL controls on it, each of course being its own window, thus having its own focus. But now I'm putting it into a custom class of its own, which these 3 controls will no longer exist (they were only there in version 1 as a prototype) and I need to now somehow mimic the focus in these different regions.

I guess similar to something as simple as a TListBox, where certain items within that control get the focus instead of the entire control its self.

Here's a picture to help demonstrate what I'm making...

[image]

The one on the top is the original with the buttons. But the one on the bottom is the new one I'm building which is all custom drawn.

To elaborate, I'd like to see if Windows already has special handling for this type of scenario before I go and re-invent the wheel.

I'm not looking for the "Easiest" way to accomplish this. And I also do not want recommendations to revert back to how I had it before, because there's many reasons I don't want 1 control with multiple other controls within. I just need a yes or no, with an explanation.

**More**

I just realized the main concern is the use of the `tab` key. The control has to first get the focus, start the focus on whichever sub-item it's supposed to, then respond to `tab` on my command until it reaches the end, then pass the tabbing over to the next control. Then it also needs shift+tab as well. How on earth would I implement this tabbing? That's where I got stuck, but it just struck me that this is the main reason I'm asking.

Comment: List items do not receive focus (as in the sense of keyboard focus), it's the box that has the focus. If it had been the case you wouldn't be able to navigate items for instance by pressing the first char of an item. Items only have a visual indication of being focused/selected. Nevertheless you can simulate the behavior of course..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz So there's no additional Windows handling for this scenario? I figured that would be the case, but I wasn't sure if there were some special handling routines already built-in to Windows.

Comment: No, as far as the OS is concerned a window is what can receive the keyboard focus, it's up to you how to partition it. Not sure if it's exactly related with your question, but see "[Keyboard Focus and Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646267%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_Keyboard_Focus_and_Activation)".

Comment: I am not so sure but you may head [here](http://objecteverywhere.chez-alice.fr/delph.html) and search for "Navigateur hyperbolique" in the huge page in french. It about a delphi component adopting the focus & context concept.

Comment: I think it's time to ask a new question

Comment: And I've already concluded the answer is no, I just need someone to emphasize that in an answer so I can accept it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't get windows to recognize multiple points of keyboard focus inside the same window handle, since each control with a window handle either has, or does not have, keyboard focus. The "inner focus" between multiple controls is up to you to sort out.

As you already knew, the most simple way to accomplish this is to have multiple sub-controls with their own window-handles, which is what you said you are doing:

```
TMyThreeEditControls = class(TControl) //  parent has no window handle!!!!
    protected
        FEdit1:TEdit;
        FEdit2:TEdit;
        FEdit3:TEdit;
    ...
end
```

In the situation above, the parent control is a TControl, it creates several sub controls, in my example above, all three have their own window handles, and thus Windows can display keyboard focus when you hit tab, and handle mouse focus as part of Windows's common controls library's functionality.

In short, the  "composite" approach where you include sub-objects (other controls) in your main control, which you are trying to move away from is in fact, the only way to let Windows do most of the work.

On the other hand, what you might be looking for is not a way to have a control paint itself, but some code to make something look like it is focused, in your own custom painting routines, if that is what you are looking for, you should look into the VCL source code or this [link](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2006/qt/focusrectangle.htm) on about.com for examples on how to tell Windows to draw a focus rectangle, etc. The about.com link is an imitation and does not use real windows code to draw focus in a Windows-theme aware way.

Update: it is possible that what you are also looking for is the way to determine if mouse co-ordinates are within a specified rectangle (the rectangle represents a button in your case) and if so, to draw a "hot state" for the button.     There are more sub-tasks than this to accomplish if you wish to build a control yourself, I recommend you study existing controls such as TStringGrid and TCategoryButtons in the VCL source code, to see the MouseMove, MouseDown, and MouseUp handling code you will need to do the things you are trying to do. In particular, StringGrid source code is the way to see how the "tab key" can be used within a single control with a single window handle, because in that control the tab key can be used (if the right options are turned on) to navigate among all the cells inside the string grid, as if each one was a separate control, even though it is all one control.

Comment: Indeed this may be the most simple way to do it, but I'm not looking for simple (not that I'm looking for difficult instead) but I just wanted to see if Windows already has such a functionality built in - but it looks like the answer is unfolding as no. This is exactly how I built version 1 of this already, now I'm trying to move away from multiple controls.

Comment: Of course it has all that functionality "built in". It is called the Windows Common Controls.  Your question isn't making sense. What you seem to be asking is "is it built in, in  a way I can use without using the multiple controls".  In which case, the answer is "the painting code is built in as methods you can call to draw focus rectangles", but the tracking of who has focus, is your job now.

Comment: I posted that before you finished your answer - the second part of that is yes - I want 1 paint procedure, 1 handle, and to mimic the focus in the different areas. Thanks for the link :D

Comment: I'm more than aware that Windows already has focus built-in to its controls. I was wondering if Windows has any support of "1 control with multiple focus points".

Comment: and these controls which are going onto it are merely buttons, which I'm implementing a way to capture the mouse position and identify which button it's over - I excluded that from the question because it is irrelevant. But the point is, I'm not using controls such as a combo box, which absolutely have to have their own handles. In the end - 1 control with multiple control-like features shown at once.

Comment: If you write a control, Jerry, then Windows is not aware that you have  written any such thing. If you do not use common controls then you take over the entire job of managing painting, message handling, focus handling, drawing, and so on, yourself.  There are many functions in Delphi VCL and in Windows API to make this easier, but it requires, in the end, a lot of co-ordination and careful work by you, which cannot be automated by any means know to me. For a sample of a control that does all the things you're talking about, have a look at TStringGrid's source code in the VCL.

Comment: And if it's a "bunch of buttons" in one control, the CategoryButtons control in the VCL is a lovely bit of code. Perhaps you could learn everything you need to do what you want to do from modifying a local copy of it.  I recommend that approach;  Copy it, create a version control repo, and hack it into something else. Now you will know how the pros write components. And you will learn a LOT.

Comment: Nope, this is a more customized layout of dynamic buttons, very much like the windows taskbar. I don't want to create a bunch of buttons, instead I want to recognize mouse focus in certain areas of the one control's canvas.

Comment: I'll accept if you change your answer to direct it at the fact that no Windows functionality supports focus to certain regions of a control, and that I have to manage it myself.

Answer (score 4):

About the handling of the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key - it should be something like this: you handle the [WM_GETDLGCODE message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to indicate that you want to proccess the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key, ie

```
TMyControl = ...
  protected
     procedure WMGetDlgCode(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_GETDLGCODE;
     procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
...
procedure TMyControl.WMGetDlgCode(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Msg.Result:= Msg.Result or DLGC_WANTTAB;
end;
```

and the in the overriden `KeyDown` method you decide what to do in response of it, something like

```
procedure TMyControl.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if(Key = VK_TAB)then begin
     if(ssShift in Shift)then begin
        if(first subcontrol is focused) set focus to previous control on parent
        else set focus to previous child area
     end else begin
        if(last subcontrol is focused) set focus to next control on parent
        else set focus to next child area
     end;
  end else inherited;
end;
```

Comment: +1 great stuff, although I was actually just about to ask another question about tabbing specifically, but thanks, great help.

Comment: This would be a better answer to a question about this exact matter. "How to add tab-handling to a custom control "

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this is to use one edit box that you re-use for each region that you want to have "focused". This is essentially how Delphi's grids work.

When the user clicks in that area (or hits the tab key into your control) you set the edit controls text to the data in that area, set the edit controls bounds to the area and make it visible. When the user exits the control (by clicking out of it or tabbing) you hide the edit control. If you make your control accept the tab key, you can make it "edit" the next area when they hit tab and exit it when they are in the last area.

Then it's just house keeping to make sure you store the entered data in the right spot in your component.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've actually one that before with combo boxes on grids, and I don't need to create any VCL controls. It's essentially just buttons with special handling, and I can easily accomplish that by reserving regions of the control's canvas for drawing and mouse events by using Hit Test. The trouble comes when I want to put focus on one of these regions.

Comment: TCanvas.DrawFocusRect is your friend then. :) Keep track of which region is focused, and draw focus rect when you draw the control.

Comment: Well actually part of my goal is to skin the entire app and eliminate the dotted line of focus, but that's a far different subject. I'm putting my own focus around controls, as they aren't all rectangular. +1 for the good tips though